# using ng-repeat with Jquery causing trouble

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using AngularJS with a HTML5 template with jQuery. I'm facing problem with the toggle div (if you toggle. it further opens a form.) I've a collection something like

```
 CategoryName1 
 CategoryType1
     ItemCollection1[]
     ItemCollection2[]

 CategoryName2 
 CategoryType2
     ItemCollection1[]
     ItemCollection2[]
```

I want to display this collection something like this

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-1"  ng-repeat="cat in    categories">
   {{cat.Name}}, {{cat.Type}}
       <div class="item-list right-checkout"  ng-repeat="item in cat.Items">
          {{item.Name}}, {{item.Price}} <button class="toggle">Option</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

the above toggle button toggles a div below

```
  <div class="dropdown-option clearfix">
        <div class="dropdown-details">
            <form class="default-form">
                <h5>Please Select Your Option</h5>
                     <h6>Option</h6> 
                       ------
                       ------
            </form>
         </div>
   </div>
```

problem I'm facing is.. as soon as I provide ng-repeat the toggle buttons stops working.

I tried to create the nested directive, becuause there are nested ng-repeat. it didnt work. But then when I included my custom Javascript (that handles the toggle) with the child template. It worked "with a but". the but is it toggles continuously in loop equals to parent items count. 
Please guide me how to overcome this issue .

or is there a way I call directive on UI like below

```
 <div ng-repeat="cat in categories">
      <div show-categories category="cat">
         <div item-categories item="cat.Items"> </div> /*displays items withing that categories)*/
       </div>
 </div>
```

All I want is to avoid ng-repeat inside directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I do toggle with a scope parameter and `ng-show`/`ng-if`, not sure if this is what you want.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope) {
  $scope.parents = [{
    name: "parent 1",
    children: [{
      name: "p1 child 1",
      form: "p1 c1 form"
    }, {
      name: "p1 child 2",
      form: "p1 c2 form"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "parent 2",
    children: [{
      name: "p2 child 1",
      form: "p2 c1 form"
    }, {
      name: "p2 child 2",
      form: "p2 c2 form"
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    {{parent.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
      {{child.name}}
      <button type="button" ng-click="child.isOpen = !child.isOpen">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  <div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <div ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
      <div ng-show="!!child.isOpen">{{child.form}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Icycool for the reply. but I want to use my HTML templates for UI features and animations.

Comment: Yea you can replace with your html templates but you might need to change the structure a bit. IIRC jquery dropdown targets by position so you can't really put all the buttons in 1 place and all the forms together. You can try making a demo without angular and see whether it works, then translate to angular `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks IcyCool, this is the simplest solution I could use. please excuse me I'm very new to angular so was trying to dig deeper using directives and all. But simple ng-show worked for me.  :(  .....   :)